# How do you enable TLS1.3 in nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, openssl

i tried to configure nginx 1.11.12 with TLS1.3 but every time i failed.
Can you please explain me how to do that using nginx 1.11.12 and openssl 1.1.0e ?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  You're more likely to get an answer if you include useful details like what you've tried and the specific error message you're getting.  Feel free to edit your question to include the useful details.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. OpenSSL 1.1.0 doesn't support TLS 1.3, this will be  available in OpenSSL 1.1.1

Comment: Thank You, do you know when is going to be released ?

Comment: No. It will be the next release  though. https://www.openssl.org/policies/roadmap.html and this will of course only happen after TLS 1.3 has been finalized - it is still a draft.